# how we can implement a auger function to automate unittest

Tags: python

I have written a code for Snake and ladder game (text based not GUI based).So now I want to  write test cases of it by using Auger which automatically gives unnittest.

```
class Snakegame:

    def main():

        while True:
            play = input("Press Enter to Play and  Q to quit the game: ")
            if play == "":
                print("Mode select (Single player/ Multiplayer)")
                mode = input("Enter \"S\" for sigle player and \"M\" for multiplayer: ")
                if mode == "S" or mode == "s":
                    player2 = "Computer"
                    num_players = 2
                else:
                    num_players = int(input("enter no. of players: "))
                player1 = input("enter player 1 name: ")
                if (mode == "m" or mode == "m") and 5 > num_players > 1:
                    player2 = input("enter player 2 name: ")
                if 5 > num_players > 2:
                    player3 = input("enter player 3 name: ")
                if 5 > num_players > 3:
                    player4 = input("enter player 4 name: ")
                    print('\n')
                print('\n')
                while True:
                    play2 = input("press ennter to start")
                    if play2 == "":
                        player1_score = player2_score = player3_score = player4_score = 0
                        while True:
                            if 5 > num_players > 1:

                                player1_score = turn_indicator(player1, player1_score)
                                if player1_score == 100:
                                    break
                                player2_score = turn_indicator(player2, player2_score)
                                if player2_score == 100:
                                    break
                            if 5 > num_players > 2:
                                player3_score = turn_indicator(player3, player3_score)
                                if player3_score == 100:
                                    break
                            if 5 > num_players > 3:
                                player4_score = turn_indicator(player4, player4_score)
                                if player4_score == 100:
                                    break
                            print("________________________________________________________________")

                    break
            elif play == "q" or play == "Q":
                break
                quit

def start(): #this function is outside of the class
    Snakegame.main(True)
```

general syntax for auger is like this

```
import auger

with auger.magic([ <any list of modules or classes> ]):
    <any code that exercises your application>
```

what i use is in this format

```
with auger.magic([Snakegame]):
    start()
```

when i write code in this format it gives me error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/mayank.sharma/PycharmProjects/game/sample/snakelad.py", line 10, in 
>       with auger.magic([Snakegame]):
>     File "C:\Users\mayank.sharma\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\auger__init__.py", line 24, in **init**
>       self._generator = generator or DefaultGenerator()
>     File "C:\Users\mayank.sharma\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\auger\generator\default.py", line 17, in **init**
>       Generator.**init**(self)
>     File "C:\Users\mayank.sharma\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\auger\generator\generator.py", line 24, in **init**
>       init_module_names()
>     File "C:\Users\mayank.sharma\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\auger\generator\generator.py", line 12, in init_module_names
>       for name, mod in modules
>     File "C:\Users\mayank.sharma\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\auger\generator\generator.py", line 13, in 
>       if hasattr(mod, '**file**')
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I have also taken reference of this blog                       http://chrislaffra.blogspot.com/2016/12/auger-automatic-unit-test-generation.html

Comment: Looks like you are writing javarish Python. Your class does not serve any purpose and everything could be a function.

Comment: Can u tell me if by using only methods we can use auger and unnitest can be written @KlausD.